# Mercedes S205 unknown fault code: 562CFF6C

Tags: obd-ii, mercedes-benz

My car machine readed a fault codes with Bosch system from Mercedes W205 (2014) C180 car and they have found an unknown fault code in ABS/ESP system:

fault code is: 562CFF2C

After deletion of the fault codes and reread the error codes it changed to 562CFF6C

It is also unknown for Bosch system.

What is the meaning of this code?

Comment: I'm guessing those are hexadecimal numbers, not error codes. My understanding of error codes; P for emissions, C for chassis, U for network and B for body codes. ABS falls under C codes. All error codes are the letter followed by four numbers. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I get this error code from mechanic, they use the BOSCH ODB reader. This code is placed where C/U/B codes are common in riport (I compared to other riport). It seems to me a hexa code. Text message is unknown error.

Comment: Perhaps this is a history code not affecting everyday use and can be ignored. History codes may be data for M-B use in developing in-house stats. If the CEL/MIL  and/or ABS indicator is off after a reset, you're fine. However, if the engine or abs indicator remains on, you may need to go to M-B for proper diagnosis of this hex (?) code. Worse case scenario is abs is disabled but brakes are operable without abs. If electronic stability control is another feature, it would be disabled too.

Answer (score 2):

First off, roughly speaking, there are two kinds of DTC codes, OBD2 (4 bytes), and UDS/KWP (6 + 2 bytes). `562CFF2C` is probably one of the latter kind, with `562CFF` being the actual fault and `2C` being the status.

That said, in contrast to OBD2 where at least the basic structure is standardized, the UDS/KWP codes are completely vendor- and ECU-specific.